# Display tableView under status bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to display my `UITableView`'s content under the status bar upon app launch (it can be achieved now by scrolling).

This is my current result:

[image]

But I'd like it to appear like this:

[image]

I've set these attributes for the `UINavigationController`

[image]

And I've tried to adjust the insets like so in `viewDidLoad`:

```
[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
```

However, it doesn't display as desired.

Comment: are you creating the tableview via code? or dragging it to storyboard?

Comment: @SahebRoy it's a storyboard created `UITableViewController`

Comment: how about using a uiviewcontroller subclass and using a tableview instead?
Or you can untick extended edges -  "Under Top Bars", and check the result once

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the code in  this method- `-viewDidLayoutSubview()`

```
[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
```

Comment: Easier syntax: `self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;`

Answer (score 6):

set the tableView contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior property

`tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never`

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: -UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: When I click the status bar, the table view goes to zero content inset, which means it works but generates another problem..